# Central force system and stable circular orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Reviewing for my ODE final and this is a question asked:

Consider the central force system with potential $V(x) = x^p$. For what values of $p \in \mathbb{R}$ are there stable circular orbits?

While I know what a stable circular orbit is in dynamical systems I'm pretty unfamiliar with the physics behind this so I'm not quite sure what to do. 
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~moloney/PH314/circstability.htm

Comment: Do you mean a system of form $\ddot{x} = -V'(x), \; x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Evgeny yes, that is what I mean. I'm still confused could you please provide some input?

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand question to full extent. What does "stable circular" mean here? By the way, for any value of $p$ the system has a first integral $\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} + V(x) = {\rm const}$, but the way how level sets look like for sure depends on $p$. Maybe that's the key here?

Comment: @Evgeny that's what I was able to figure out. I believe by stable circular it was meant that the $\omega$ and $\alpha$ limit sets are equal.